# UI5 CheckBox Issue in sap.m.Table

Tags: checkbox, focus, sapui5, vertical-scrolling

I have an sap.m.Table populated with a number of items. One of the columns in the table contains a checkbox allowing the user to select / deselect it for a particular item.

I have an issue where the table scrolls automatically in the following case:

1. I change focus to another application on my computer. The specific application makes no difference.
2. I return to the UI5 application containing the table but I do NOT click anywhere in the application.
3. I scroll down the list using my mouse scroll wheel. I still have not clicked in the UI5 app in any way including the table's scroll bars so focus is still not in the UI5 app.
4. I select / deselect the check box for any random item in the list that within view which obviously places focus back to the UI5 app.
5. The list then scrolls on it's own as if it returns to the position in the list prior to the scroll being performed in step #3 above and selects / deselects a checkbox for a completely different item. It as if the list is retaining it's visible position on the screen and returns to that position to make it visible again on the screen.

If anyone can shed some light on this, requires further clarifying details and/or can suggest a work-a-round that would be great.

Thank you

*** UPDATE ***
December 16, 2022:
[Here](https://codepen.io/tvdm12000/pen/OJEKOgz) is an example in CodePen. I additionally noticed that it only happens if I first select a check box for an item, change focus to another application, then return to the UI5 app as per step #2 above.

*** UPDATE #2 ***
Thank you @Marc who identified work-a-rounds as per his comment below.

```
 z
```

Comment: I tried to recreate this "bug" in the SAP sample page ([for example here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableMultiSelectMode)) but wasn't able to. What version are you using? Could you provide a small sample with your setup?

Comment: Thank you @Marc for taking a look at this. I have updated my question to include sample code on CodePen which duplicates the issue.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. I was able to "fix" it in two different ways: 1) Remove "sticky" 2) Remove `<App>` and `<Page>` elements. This is probably why I wasn't able to reproduce it with the samples (they don't run in an `<App>` container). So this might be a bug in UI5.

Comment: @Marc, thank you, thank you. I hadn't thought of either of those. I have removed the "sticky" from my full application and it corrected the issue.